# MongoDb - query - empty result even when it is not empty

Tags: mongodb, spring-repositories

I try to write some aggregation queries for MongoDB. I'm pretty new in it so I have problem find where is problem here :

```
{
    "aggregate": "__collection__",
    "pipeline": [
        {
            "$unwind": "$studia"
        },
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": {
                    "course": "$course",
                    "start": "$start"
                },
                "n": {
                    "$sum": 1
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$sort": {
                "n": -1
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This query is generated by Java. It should count and sum how many times there are some courses starting in some date. But it return empty result. That is wrong.

My documents are :

```
  {
        "_id": "1006262",
        "name": "Kugujalu",
        "lname": "Najahalovu",
        "studia": [
            {
                "id": "992",
                "start": {
                    "$date": "1998-08-31T22:00:00.000Z"
                },
                "end": {
                    "$date": "2003-06-10T22:00:00.000Z"
                },
               "course": "MCH",
            }
        ],
        "_class": "com.mongodb.MongoStudent"
    }
 {
        "_id": "1006263",
        "name": "Elkjuu",
        "lname": "Xjikuju",
        "studia": [
            {
                "id": "992",
                "start": {
                    "$date": "1998-08-31T22:00:00.000Z"
                },
                "end": {
                    "$date": "2003-06-10T22:00:00.000Z"
                },
               "course": "MCH",
            }
        ],
        "_class": "com.mongodb.MongoStudent"
    }
```

So I want query which return result like :

```
"start": 1998-08-31T22:00:00.000Z, "course": "MCH", "n": 2
```

Any idea, where is problem ?

This generate me query :

```
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(unwind("studia"), group("course","start").count().as("n"),
                sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "n"));
```

Comment: `{ "$group": {  "_id": { "course": "$studia.course",  "start": "$studia,start" }, ...` So your Java code is not including the correct "full path" to the elements inside the "unwound" array. The output looks like it's from spring-mongo. Care to share the code?

Comment: @NeilLunn What you mean, not correct full path ?

Comment: `$studia.course` and NOT `$course`. There is no element called `$course`. That's why you don't get results. So your code should be `group("studia.skratka","studia.zaciatok_studia")`. Adding `studia` and the "dot" `.` to the beginning. That's how it works.

Comment: well i change but it still give me empty result

Comment: It's not helping that you're using different field names in your Java code and data to what you are showing here. If you actually run the corrections I gave you in the first comment against the actual document you included in the question from the mongo shell, then you will see the correct result. See how the query is supposed to work first and then please try and present consistent code.

Comment: it was different because I rename some fields in document ever since I wrote a question. But this code with don't work on any collection, new one or old one.